# Add two columns in text file and load to sql

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

I am trying to add two columns and then enter them into mysql on my linux system.

```
id , v1 , v2 , v3 , v4 , v5 , v6
5  , 8  , 1  , 9  , 9  , 9  , 6
1  , 4  , 9  , 3  , 5  , 1  , 7
7  , 7  , 2  , 9  , 9  , 2  , 3
8  , 1  , 5  , 1  , 6  , 4  , 7
1  , 3  , 5  , 6  , 4  , 7  , 3
5  , 10 , 6  , 8  , 6  , 3  , 5
4  , 5  , 2  , 1  , 9  , 4  , 2
```

I would like to add v1 and v2 and enter this to mysql. ie the actual data loaded to sql would be this:

```
id , newval , v3 , v4 , v5 , v6
5  , 9      , 9  , 9  , 9  , 6
1  , 13     , 3  , 5  , 1  , 7
7  , 9      , 9  , 9  , 2  , 3
8  , 6      , 1  , 6  , 4  , 7
1  , 8      , 6  , 4  , 7  , 3
5  , 16     , 8  , 6  , 3  , 5
4  , 7      , 1  , 9  , 4  , 2
```

Any idea how I can use this directly using LOAD TABLE?
My current workaround is thus:

```
cat a.txt  | awk -F "," '{print $1","$2+$3","$4","$5","$6","$7}' > b.txt
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/b.txt' INTO TABLE values;
```

Thanks in advance
DY

Comment: +1 for well organized question, with sample data, required output and some working code. Sorry, I don't know about LOAD TABLE in mysql.  Good luck and Keep posting! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [documentation for `LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)... which is unfortunately really poorly organized. The short answer is that you can assign columns to variables (e.g. `@v1`) and then use those variables in a `SET` clause to set column values programmatically. I'll just quote the relevant section from the docs:

> The column list can contain either column names or user variables. With user variables, the `SET` clause enables you to perform transformations on their values before assigning the result to columns.
>
> User variables in the `SET` clause can be used in several ways. The following example uses the first input column directly for the value of `t1.column1`, and assigns the second input column to a user variable that is subjected to a division operation before being used for the value of `t1.column2`:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
>   INTO TABLE t1
>   (column1, @var1)
>   SET column2 = @var1/100;
> ```

So in your case you'd want something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/b.txt'
  INTO TABLE values
  (id , @v1 , @v2 , v3 , v4 , v5 , v6)
  SET newval = @v1 + @v2;
```

This sets the `id`, `v3`, `v4`, `v5`, and `v6` columns from the 1st and 4th through 7th columns in the input file, respectively, and assigns the 2nd and 3rd columns to the variables `@v1` and `@v2`. Then it sets the `newval` column to the result of `@v1 + @v2`.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I feel embarrassed about having asked this question as the documentation did cover that. You answer made it even more clearer.